# How is memset working in this snippet of code?

Tags: c++

I think this snippet of code is enough to get the idea of what I'm doing.
I'm using getline to read input data from a text file that has lines that might look something like this: The cat is fat/And likes to sing

From searching around the internet I was able to get it working, but I'd like to better understand WHY it is working. My primary question is how the

```
memcpy(id, buffer, temp - buffer);
```

line is working. I read what `memcpy()` does but do not understand how the temp - buffer part is working. 
So from my understanding I'm setting `*temp` to the '/' in that line. Then I'm copying the line up until the '/' into it. But how does the temp, which is at '/' minus the buffer (which is the whole line from `getline`) work out to just be The cat is fat?

Hopefully that made some sense.

```
#define MAX_SIZE    255

char buffer[MAX_SIZE + 1] = { 0 };
cin.getline(buffer, MAX_SIZE);

memset(id, 0, 256);
memset(title, 0, 256);

char* temp = strchr(buffer, '/');
memcpy(id, buffer, temp - buffer);
temp++;
strcpy(title, temp);
```

Also, if I can double dip, why would MAX_SIZE be defined at 255 but MAX_SIZE+1 is often used. Does this have to do with a delimiter or white space at the end of a line?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure your title is what you intended. The `memset` calls in this code are most straight-forward: "fill this memory region at this starting address with this octet for this many repetitions". I would think the `temp-buffer` in the **`memcpy`** call would be more interesting (and its a *pointer-difference* calculation, worth googling).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is simply a bad code.:)
I would write it like

```
const size_t MAX_SIZE = 256

char buffer[MAX_SIZE] = {};

std::cin.getline( buffer, MAX_SIZE );

id[0] = '\0';
title[0] = '\0';

if ( char* temp = strchr( buffer, '/' ) )
{
    std::memcpy( id, buffer, temp - buffer );
    id[temp - buffer] = '\0';
    std::strcpy( title, temp + 1 );
}
else
{
    std::strcpy( id, buffer );
}
```

As for `memcpy` in this statement

```
memcpy(id, buffer, temp - buffer);
```

then it copies temp - buffer bytes from buffer to id. As id was previously set to zeroes then after memcpy it will contain a string with terminating zero.

Answer (score 2):

You're question concerns *pointer-difference* calculation, part of the family of arithmetic operations that are done in *pointer-arithmetic*.

Most beginners don't have too much trouble grasping how pointer-addition works. Given this:

```
char buffer[256];
char *p = buffer + 10;
```

it is usually clear that `p` points to the 10th slot in the `buffer` char array. But you need to remember that the pointer **type** is important. The same construct you see above also works for more complicated data types:

```
struct Something
{
    char name[128];
    int ident;
    int supervisor;
} people[64];

struct Something *p = people+10; // NOTE: same line, different types
```

Just as before, `p` points to the tenth element in the array, but note the arithmetic; the size of the underlying type is used to calculate the relevant memory offset. You don't need to do it yourself. No `sizeof` required here.

So why do you care? Because just like regular math, pointer math has certain properties, one of them being the following:

```
char buffer[256];
char *p = buffer+10;   // p addresses the 10th slot in the array
size_t len = p-buffer  // len is the typed-difference between p and buffer.
```

In this case, `len` will be 10, the same as the offset of `p`. So how does this relate to your question? Well...

```
char* temp = strchr(buffer, '/');
memcpy(id, buffer, temp - buffer);
```

The horrid nature of this code aside (if there is no `'/'` in the `buffer` array the result is `temp` being `NULL`, and the ensuing memcpy will all-but-guarantee a massive segfault). This code finds the location in the string where `'/'` resides. Once it has that, the calculation `temp - buffer` uses pointer arithmetic (specifically pointer differencing) to calculate the distance between the address in `temp` and the address as the base of the array. The result is the element count **not including the slash itself**. Therefore this code copies up-to, but not including, the discovered slash, into the `id` buffer. The rest of the `id` buffer retains all the `0` values populated with the memset and therefore the string is terminated (which is way more work than you need to do, btw).

After that line, the remainder:

```
temp++;
strcpy(title, temp);
```

post-increments the temp pointer, which says "move to the next element in the array". Then the `strcpy` copies the remaining chars of the null-terminated `buffer` string into `title`. Worth noting this could have simply been:

```
strcpy(title, ++temp);
```

And likewise:

```
strcpy(title, temp+1);
```

which retains `temp` at the `'/'` position. In all of the above, the result in `title` will be the same: all chars *after* the slash, but not including it.

I hope that explains what is going on. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

There you calculate position of first `/` in buffer.

```
char* temp = strchr(buffer, '/');
```

Now `temp` points to `/` in buffer. If you want to copy this part of buffer, its enough to get pointer to start and length of string. So `temp - buffer` evaluates to length.

```
=================================
The cat is fat/And likes to sing
=================================
^             ^
buffer        temp

|    length   | = temp - buffer
```

End of null terminated string determinated by `\0` (or simply 0). So if you need to store N chars you need to allocate N+1 buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

```
MAX_SIZE+1 is reserving space for the null terminator at the end of the string ('\0')

memcpy(id, buffer, temp - buffer)
```

This is copying (temp-buffer) bytes from buffer to id.  Since strchr finds the '/' character in the input, temp is pointing inside buffer (assumiing it's found). So for example assume buffer points to a location in memory:

buffer = 0x781230001

and the third byte is the '/', after strchr, you have

temp = 0x781230003

temp - buffer therefore is 2.

HOWEVER: If the '/' is not found, then temp will not work and the code will crash.  You should check the result of strchr before doing the pointer arithmetic.